# PHP: how can I validate a Google Places formatted_address server-side?

Tags: php, google-places-api

I am building a PHP&MySQL website.
I managed to successfully use the Google Places API on the client side of my website (using JavaScript). I am passing the formatted_address (chosen by the user via the Google Places API) to the PHP script.

The trouble is, I haven't got a clue how I can validate on the server side whether or not the input is genuinely a Google Places API result, or it has been tampered with prior to submission.

I have scoured the web looking for a basic tutorial of how to use the Google Places API via to PHP to no avail.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I guess you can do that is call the google Places Api with the same input the user had given and retrieve the JSON/xml Result and check it with your form Submission,but that would be an additional request on your api key.

Usually the best practice to do this will be sending these critical data from the server to the client via JSON. I suggest you try that, this method is tedious.

Comment: Thank you, but this is my exact problem: I don't know how to use the Google Places API on the server side. Can you give me some example code of how this is done?

Comment: Google has the best Example code [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro). If you want to use it with your php on server side i suggest you follow this method. just do `file_get_contents(URL)` on the Google Api Url and get the JSON object,parse it and send it to your client side.